# require/typed for mrlib/path-dialog error message

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to use `path-dialog%` from mrlib/path-dialog in a typed/racket program, but it is complaining that I need to use require/typed to import it.

I'm sure this is an easy one for someone familiar with require/typed, but I am not that person. The main gui library and the main db library are available in typed versions, but it seems that the mrlib extensions are not available in typed versions.

Could someone please be so kind as to explain how to fix this error?

Thank you.

The exact error message is:

```
Type Checker: missing type for identifier;
 consider using `require/typed' to import it
  identifier: path-dialog%
  from module: mrlib/path-dialog in: path-dialog%
```

Comment: I found a work-around but not a solution. The work-around involved creating a procedure that called the path-dialog and then declaring the procedure in the require/typed statement like this

`(require/typed "test-dialog.rkt" [showpd (-> (Option Path))])`

Then I discovered the `get-file` procedure and no longer need path-dialog, but I am still curious how to import classes.

Comment: Have the same issue with libuuid and would love to know the answer